# Want to Push another View from current view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am doing paypal integration and my project is working good.

But i want to push my Next view from my current view. first i used Navigation Controller but now i want to push it with out navigation controller.

I used the syntax with Navigation controller is

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[NextViewController alloc] initWithURL:[ECNetworkHandler sharedInstance].redirectURL returnURL:RETURN_URL cancelURL:CANCEL_URL] autorelease] animated:TRUE];
```

And i used the syntax to push another view controller without navigation controller is

```
NextViewController *webVcustome = [[NextViewController alloc]initWithURL:[ECNetworkHandler sharedInstance].redirectURL returnURL:RETURN_URL cancelURL:CANCEL_URL];
[self.view addSubview:webVcustome.view];
```

With Navigation it works but without navigation it don't.

What should i do to push the view controller.

Comment: Can you tell me why you don't want to use navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of adding a subview call `presentViewController:animated:completion`, like this:

```
[self presentViewController:webVcustome animated:YES completion:nil];
```

for more information of this message take a look to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a)

Comment: Thanks bro...My reputation is not 15. otherwise i ll give you my vote... but great help...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "push" a view without using UINavigationController , I think you can only use two views to adjust their frames when they are begin "push" movement.

eg:maybe you can creat 2 subviews such as : `currentView` , `anotherView`. And then add them to the `self.view`.
maybe you can set the `currentViews` frame is `(0,0,320,480)` and `anotherViews` frame is `(320,0,320,480)` , when you want to "push" them , you can set their frame is the currentViews frame is `(-320,0,320,480)` and anotherViews frame is `(0,0,320,480)` with a `UIView animation`